# How to access to monero rpc from https javascript

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, javascript

I wrote a small javascript to test digest authentication on `monerod` and `monero-wallet-rpc`.

When running on a `http` (no tls) website, authentication works, and I get my response.

Then trying the same javascript on a `https` website, I get the folowing log output from the wallet server.

```
D handle_accept
     D New server for RPC connections, SSL autodetection
     D set m_connection_type = RPC 
     D Spawned connection #4 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:2
     D test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=1
     T [sock 0x7f9bdc044680] new connection from client.ip.address:62186 INC to server.ip.address:38083, total sockets objects 2
     T New connection from host client.ip.address: 0
     T Setting 00:00:10 expiry
     D  connection type RPC server.ip.address:38083 <--> client.ip.address:62186 (via client.ip.address:62186)
     T Setting 00:00:10.102921 expiry
     D SSL detection buffer, 517 bytes: 22 3 1 2 0 1 0 1 252
     D That looks like SSL
     D handle_accept
     D New server for RPC connections, SSL autodetection
     D set m_connection_type = RPC 
     D Spawned connection #5 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:3
     D test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=1
     T [sock 0x7f9bdc02dce0] new connection from client.ip.address:61715 INC to server.ip.address:38083, total sockets objects 3
     T New connection from host client.ip.address: 1
     T Setting 00:00:10 expiry
     D  connection type RPC server.ip.address:38083 <--> client.ip.address:61715 (via client.ip.address:61715)
     T Setting 00:00:10.072703 expiry
     D SSL detection buffer, 517 bytes: 22 3 1 2 0 1 0 1 252
     D That looks like SSL
     E SSL handshake failed, connection dropped: short read
     E SSL handshake failed
     T Closed connection from host client.ip.address: 2
     D SSL handshake success
     T [sock 9] Socket destroyed
     D Destructing connection #4 to client.ip.address
     T [sock 8] Some not success at read: sslv3 alert bad certificate:336151570
     T [sock 8] Some problems at read: sslv3 alert bad certificate:336151570
     T Closed connection from host client.ip.address: 1
     T [sock 8] Socket destroyed
     D Destructing connection #3 to client.ip.address
```

And I get a generic error in Firefox.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://server.ip.address:38083/json_rpc. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

What am I missing? Do I need to tell monero about my certificate?

EDIT: Added a successful session. No HTTPS and No certificates.

Website and the monero stuff is on the same host/ip-address.

```
 T Throttle <<< global-IN: packet of ~496b  (from 496 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=9.757]    0[w=9.757] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [496 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 T HTTP HEAD:
 T Host: host.example.com:38083
 T User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
 T Accept: */*
 T Accept-Language: en,da;q=0.5
 T Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 T Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
 T Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
 T Referer: http://host.example.com/test-05/
 T Origin: http://host.example.com
 T DNT: 1
 T Connection: keep-alive
 T Pragma: no-cache
 T Cache-Control: no-cache
 T 
 T HTTP_RESPONSE_HEAD: << 
 T HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 T Server: Epee-based
 T Content-Length: 0
 T Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 14:55:13 GMT
 T Accept-Ranges: bytes
 T Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://host.example.com
 T Access-Control-Expose-Headers: www-authenticate
 T Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With
 T Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS
 T 
 T Moving counter buffer by 1 second 0 < 300414 (last time 0)
 T Throttle throttle_speed_out: packet of ~373b  (from 373 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=1]    0[w=1] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [373 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 D do_send_chunk() NOW SENSD: packet=373 B
 T Setting 00:05:00 expiry
 T Setting 00:05:00 expiry
 T [client.ip.addr:60290 INC] [sock 8] Async send calledback 373
 D handle_accept
 D New server for RPC connections, SSL autodetection
 D set m_connection_type = RPC 
 D Spawned connection #8 to 0.0.0.0 currently we have sockets count:3
 D test, connection constructor set m_connection_type=1
 T [sock 0x7f147801ec40] new connection from client.ip.addr:34239 INC to server.ip.addr:38083, total sockets objects 3
 T New connection from host client.ip.addr: 1
 T Setting 00:00:10 expiry
 D  connection type RPC server.ip.addr:38083 <--> client.ip.addr:34239 (via client.ip.addr:34239)
 T Setting 00:00:09.738196 expiry
 D SSL detection buffer, 538 bytes: 80 79 83 84 32 47 106 115 111
 D That does not look like SSL
 T Moving counter buffer by 1 second 0 < 300415 (last time 0)
 T Throttle throttle_speed_in: packet of ~538b  (from 538 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=1]    0[w=1] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [538 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 T Moving counter buffer by 1 second 300413 < 300415 (last time 300414)
 T Moving counter buffer by 1 second 300414 < 300415 (last time 300415)
 T Throttle <<< global-IN: packet of ~538b  (from 538 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=9.159]    0[w=9.159] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [538 0 496 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 T HTTP HEAD:
 T Host: host.example.com:38083
 T User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
 T Accept: */*
 T Accept-Language: en,da;q=0.5
 T Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 T Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 T Content-Length: 61
 T Origin: http://host.example.com
 T DNT: 1
 T Connection: keep-alive
 T Referer: http://host.example.com/test-05/
 T Pragma: no-cache
 T Cache-Control: no-cache
 T 
 T HTTP_RESPONSE_HEAD: << 
 T HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 T Server: Epee-based
 T Content-Length: 98
 T Content-Type: text/html
 T Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 14:55:14 GMT
 T Accept-Ranges: bytes
 T Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://host.example.com
 T Access-Control-Expose-Headers: www-authenticate
 T Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS
 T WWW-authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5,realm="monero-rpc",nonce="TxiQqEIvHWWbjks8rvdMRA==",stale=false
 T WWW-authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,realm="monero-rpc",nonce="TxiQqEIvHWWbjks8rvdMRA==",stale=false
 T 
 T Moving counter buffer by 1 second 0 < 300415 (last time 0)
 T Throttle throttle_speed_out: packet of ~665b  (from 665 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=1]    0[w=1] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [665 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 D do_send_chunk() NOW SENSD: packet=665 B
 T Setting 00:05:00 expiry
 T Setting 00:05:00 expiry
 T [client.ip.addr:34239 INC] [sock 9] Async send calledback 665
 T Throttle throttle_speed_in: packet of ~758b  (from 758 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=1]    0[w=1] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [1296 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 T Throttle <<< global-IN: packet of ~758b  (from 758 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=9.425]    0[w=9.425] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [1296 0 496 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 T HTTP HEAD:
 T Host: host.example.com:38083
 T User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
 T Accept: */*
 T Accept-Language: en,da;q=0.5
 T Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 T Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 T Authorization: Digest username="rpc_user", realm="monero-rpc", nonce="TxiQqEIvHWWbjks8rvdMRA==", uri="/", algorithm="MD5", response="34638b90a7ae09644c8559fa7e1dc4a4", qop="auth", nc=00000001, cnonce="bd5fd9b093dccaa1"
 T Content-Length: 61
 T Origin: http://host.example.com
 T DNT: 1
 T Connection: keep-alive
 T Referer: http://host.example.com/test-05/
 T Pragma: no-cache
 T Cache-Control: no-cache
 T 
 I HTTP [client.ip.addr] POST /json_rpc
 I [client.ip.addr:34239 INC] Calling RPC method get_version
 D /json_rpc[get_version] processed with 0/0/0ms
 T HTTP_RESPONSE_HEAD: << 
 T HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
 T Server: Epee-based
 T Content-Length: 104
 T Content-Type: application/json
 T Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 14:55:14 GMT
 T Accept-Ranges: bytes
 T Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://host.example.com
 T Access-Control-Expose-Headers: www-authenticate
 T Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS
 T 
 T Throttle throttle_speed_out: packet of ~434b  (from 434 b) Speed AVG=   0[w=1]    0[w=1] /  Limit=16 KiB/sec  [1099 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 D do_send_chunk() NOW SENSD: packet=434 B
 T Setting 00:05:00 expiry
 T Setting 00:05:00 expiry
 T [client.ip.addr:34239 INC] [sock 9] Async send calledback 434
 T [sock 8] Some not success at read: End of file:2
 T [sock 8] peer closed connection
 T Closed connection from host client.ip.addr: 2
 T [sock 8] Socket destroyed
 D Destructing connection #6 to client.ip.addr
 T [sock 9] Some not success at read: End of file:2
 T [sock 9] peer closed connection
 T Closed connection from host client.ip.addr: 1
 T [sock 9] Socket destroyed
 D Destructing connection #7 to client.ip.addr
```

Certificate trusted by Firefox:

[image]

The code that does the talking:

```
function httpClient (config, callback) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = () => {
      //Step 4: Receive original request data
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        callback({
          result: xhr.status,
          message: xhr.statusText,
          response: xhr.responseText
          })
      } else {
        callback({
          result: xhr.status,
          message: xhr.statusText,
          response: xhr.responseText
          })
      }
    };

    xhr.onerror = (e) => {
      console.log("Error:", e);
      console.log({
        result: xhr.status,
        message: xhr.statusText,
        response: xhr.responseText
      });
      callback({
          result: xhr.status,
          message: xhr.statusText,
          response: 'Some error ocurred during this request.'
        })
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      if (xhr.readyState >= 2 && xhr.status == 401) {
        console.log("readyState:", xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.statusText);

        let authHeader = xhr.getResponseHeader('www-authenticate');
        let authObject = parseResponseHeader(authHeader);
        let authResponse = buildAuthorizeHeader(config.auth, authObject);
        config.headers["Authorization"] = authResponse;
        xhr.abort();
        httpClient(config, callback);
      }
      else
        console.log("readyState:", xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
    };

    config.protocol = config.protocol.replace(/\:$/, '');

    let encodedURI = encodeURI(config.protocol + '://' + config.url);
    xhr.open(config.method, encodedURI, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(config.headers)) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value);
    }

    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    if (config.method.toUpperCase() == 'POST' && typeof config.data == "object" ) {
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(config.data))
    } else {
      xhr.send()
    }

    const buildAuthorizeHeader = (config, tokensObj ) => {
      tokensObj.headers["cnonce"] = 'bd5fd9b093dccaa1';
      tokensObj.headers["nc"] = '00000001';
      tokensObj.headers["algorithm"] = 'MD5';
      tokensObj.headers["method"] = 'POST';
      tokensObj.headers["domain"] = '/';

      let HA1 = CryptoJS.MD5(config.user + ':' + tokensObj.headers["realm"] + ':' + config.pass).toString();
      let HA2 = CryptoJS.MD5(tokensObj.headers["method"] + ':' + tokensObj.headers["domain"]).toString();
      let authResponse = CryptoJS.MD5(HA1 + 
        ':' + tokensObj.headers["nonce"] + 
        ':' + tokensObj.headers["nc"] + 
        ':' + tokensObj.headers["cnonce"] + 
        ':' + tokensObj.headers["qop"] + 
        ':' + HA2).toString();

      let responseContentHeader = 'Digest username="' + config.user + '"' + 
        ', realm="' + tokensObj.headers["realm"] + '"' + 
        ', nonce="' + tokensObj.headers["nonce"] + '"' + 
        ', uri="' + tokensObj.headers["domain"] + '"' + 
        ', algorithm="' + tokensObj.headers["algorithm"] + '"' +
        ', response="' + authResponse + '"' + 
        ', qop="' + tokensObj.headers["qop"] + '"' + 
        ', nc=' + tokensObj.headers["nc"] + 
        ', cnonce="' + tokensObj.headers["cnonce"] + '"';

      return responseContentHeader;
    }

    const parseResponseHeader = (h) => {
      let auth = {
        headers : {}
      };
      var scre = /^\w+/;
      var scheme = scre.exec(h);
      auth.scheme = scheme[0];

      var nvre = /(\w+)=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/g;
      var pairs = h.match(nvre);

      var vre = /(\w+)=['"]([^'"]+)['"]/;
      var i = 0;
      for (; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var v = vre.exec(pairs[i]);
        if (v) {
          auth.headers[v[1]] = v[2];
        }
      }
      return auth;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you setting `--rpc-access-control-origins` to `*` or `some.ip.address`?

Comment: No, it's a list of possible clients:
`--rpc-access-control-origins 'http://site1.example.com,https://site1.example.com,http://site2.example.com,https://site2.example.com'` Edit: There's no way of knowing who's accessing the web-site.

Comment: CORS relates to the host running your site, not the client browsing your site. Thus `*` means any host. If the js file (calling the wallet RPC) was hosted at `https://example.com/site.js`, you would need to run the wallet RPC with `--rpc-access-control-origins example.com` or `--rpc-access-control-origins *`.

Comment: The `--rpc-access-control-origins` list the websites hosting the js. The `client.ip.address` in the log is the browser accessing the website.

Comment: setting `--rpc-access-control-origins '*'` makes no difference. Same output in the log.

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK Chrome (and probably other browsers) will block access to http resources from an http loaded page.

Comment: @knaccc It appears so. After latest Firefox update, the http version has stopped working.

Comment: @knaccc I was wrong. Running `monerod` and `wallet-rpc` without certificates, accessing RPC from a HTTP website, it's working.

Comment: Btw i meant to type "block access to http resources from an https loaded page"

Comment: Okay. That would be the `CORS` thing. But this is not the case here: The request protocol used in the script, is set by `location.protocol`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `https://server.ip.address:38083/json_rpc`. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

The wallet RPC has a parameter `--rpc-access-control-origins` which you will need to set to the domain hosting your javascript.

From the help:

```
  --rpc-access-control-origins arg      Specify a comma separated list of 
                                        origins to allow cross origin resource 
                                        sharing
```

Thus if the site *hosting* the javascript is `https://www.example.com`, run the `monero-wallet-rpc` with `--rpc-access-control-origins https://www.example.com`.

Aside from this, and dependent on your browser settings, you may need to provide your own SSL certificate at wallet startup (via the `--rpc-ssl-...` wallet RPC parameters), as the browser may not like the auto-generated certificates the wallet creates. For example, some browsers strictly prohibit self-signed certificates.

Comment: I've tried with certificates. Website has a Let's Encrypt certificate, and wallet-rpc has (self signed) certificates, signed by a root the browser trust. It's `wallet-rpc` who's complaining, not the browser: `SSL handshake failed, connection dropped: short read` and `Some not success at read: sslv3 alert bad certificate:336151570`

Comment: The error in Firefox `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` is a generic response, saying I have no clue about what happened, but it's probably `CORS`. The `HTTP` website combined with no certificates at the monero end works.

Comment: "is a generic response," < not really that generic, it failed in the CORS preflight. Also, see my last paragraph/sentence.

Comment: You are kind of right in `it failed in the CORS preflight`. The browser sends the `OPTIONS` request, but never get an answer back from `wallet-rpc`. The log says: `SSL handshake failed, connection dropped: wrong version number`. Nothing is returned to the browser.

Comment: The browser tries 10 times to connect, before giving up and issue a `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`. There is never a response from `wallet-rpc`.

Comment: It's very hard to guess what your code is doing. More importantly though, why are you trying to access your wallet RPC in this way? If you just want to test javascript code against the wallet, use node.js. You're spending time solving a problem that has no real-world application.

Comment: Well. Firefox's `fetch()` api is broken. `monero-javascript` uses `fetch()` somewhere under the hood. I haven't been able to find which package is doing the actual request.  So finding a way for Firefox to talk to `monero-wallet-rpc` from a `https` website, could come in handy.

Comment: I added the code to the question.